# How to create customer attribute as dropdown and checkbox in Magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I want to create customer attribute for the field as dropdown and checkbox and must save as YES/NO in backend in Magento2?
Refer screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'is_mobile_verified', [
                'label' => 'Is Mobile Verified ?',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'visible' => false,
                'system' => false,
                'type' => 'static',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                'option' => ['values' => ['Yes', 'No']],
            ]);
```